# see changes in DOM elements via JavaScript in my Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript

i'm writing a Firefox Extension. i need listen to changes in some DOM objects and the log them.

a can't find something specific in JavaScript like DOM changing listener.
a have trouble with infinite loop.

```
function get_values(){

  var names = document.getElementsByClassName('X');

  var new_names = [];


  for (i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    if(names[i].innerText==""){
      continue
    }

    new_names.push(names[i].innerText);
  }
  return new_names
}

function check_values(names){
  new_names = get_values()

  if (new_names == names){
    return 0
  }else{
    return new_names
  }
}

do = true
var names = []
while(do){

  new_values = check_values(names)
  if ( new_values != 0){
    names = new_values

console.log('___________log_____________')
    console.log(names)


  }
}
```

without while expression code is running,but with this code i want listen to changes an log it in console.
with while expression i can't see any log in console.

i new to JavaScript(10H)

Comment: Have you looked at [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Comment: Never ever use a synchronous, infinite while loop. The only purpose that serves is to heat up your CPU. If you need something to run quite often use `setInterval(function() { ... }, 0)`

Comment: tanks. that is my answer